# Inline Annotations with AngularJs Directive

Tags: angularjs

***Note**: the code was written with TypeScript and the code below is the compiled javascript - I can provide the TypeScript if necessary.

I am trying to minify a file called bundle.js using grunt-contrib-uglify (mangle: true, beautify: true) which contains all compiled TypeScript we need for our AngularJs application.  When running the application I run into the error "Unknown provider: bProvider <- b" and have been able to find the offending directive.

The directive below did not have inline annotations so I updated the code to have them:

```
appDirectives.directive('emailShareModal', ['$rootScope', '$compile', '$timeout', 'httpService', 'shareFromEmailService', function ($rootScope, $compile, $timeout, httpService, shareFromEmailService) {
return {
    scope: {
        type: '@type',
        id: "=id",
        defaultBody: "=body",
        title: '@title'
    },
    link: function ($scope, element, attr) { return new emailShareModalDirective($scope, $rootScope, element, attr, $compile, $timeout, httpService); },
    controller: function ($scope) { return new experienceShareForm($rootScope, $scope, shareFromEmailService); }
};
}]);
```

Now if I remove the 'controller' attribute, the directive does not throw an exception, telling me the link attribute is configured properly.  Here is the experienceShareForm object being instantiated by the controller attribute:

```
var experienceShareForm = (function () {
function experienceShareForm($rootScope, $scope, shareFromEmailService) {
    var _this = this;
    this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.shareFromEmailService = shareFromEmailService;

}          

return experienceShareForm;
})();
```

I am at a loss to what may be the problem with the code - does anyone see anything amiss?  Thanks much in advance.

Comment: you can add `ng-strict-di` to the same element as your `ng-app` to have angular enforce dependency injection and output console warnings for any problematic code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller is trying to use DI but you are not specifying what is going to be injected. The minification is changing `$scope` to the variable `b` and the exception is saying that no `bProvider` can be found.

Change the following:

```
controller: function ($scope) { return new experienceShareForm($rootScope, $scope, shareFromEmailService); }
```

to the following:

```
controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) { return new experienceShareForm($rootScope, $scope, shareFromEmailService); }]
```

Note that you do not need to do this for the `link` function, because it is always called with the same objects. The `controller` function can be injected with different arguments, specified by you.

Comment: This line was a gamechanger for me: `Note that you do not need to do this for the link function`, because it broke some of my functions assigned to `this` inside my controller..